# Call WebService from a WebService with JaxWS

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I have created a WebService, and I need to call another WebService from it.
I am using the JaxWS annotations and have gotten to deploy the war onto WebSphere, only to get the exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Validation error: Web method annotations cannot exist on 
implentation when WebService.endpointInterface is set
```

My WebService is the following:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "MyServiceName",
    targetNamespace = "http://myServiceNamespace/MyServiceName",
    endpointInterface = "com.mycompany.MyServiceInterface",
    portName = "MyServiceInterface")
public class MyServiceName implements MyServiceInterface{

@WebServiceRef(YourServiceDef.class)
YourService yourService;
....
}
```

Is there a simple alternative to using @WebServiceRef?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how @WebServiceRef actually works, but whenever I want to call a WS_a from WS_b I just generate a client for WS_a and added it (as a jar) to WS_b and use it like any other class.

Comment: Could you clarify how you 'use it like any other class'?

Comment: Not sure how much clearer this can be. Generated client (or proxy like some like to call it) is simply a set of classes that can be used by the WS to make the call. Not much more to say here.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad I cannot see the complete code. But anyways, the problem is rather clear, you have annotated the method in the implementation of your webservice, this is not allowed when you have a SEI which your Webservice implements.